# how to stop running bigquery query

Tags: google-bigquery

is there any way how to cancel a running query?

i use the web interface. first i ran a series of tests on tables of 10k and than 20k rows and the response was in seconds. but than i ran  the triple join query on a table of 100k rows and it seems endless after thousand of seconds.

i just wanted to run some tests before moving all the work to bigquery but now i'm afraid it's gonna spend the whole monthly 100gb free limit + more.

the table is a simple key-value pairs of integer values.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The shell command `bq cancel job_id` will do this now. You can get the `job_id` from the *Query History* tab in the BigQuery console. If you started the query via the CLI, it will have logged the `job_id` to the standard output.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way, currently to stop a running query either via the API or the UI. You may be able to close the query builder (via the 'x' in the top right of the UI) and re-open it again to make the UI responsive again. We're currently working on this feature in the UI.

It is surprising that the query would take so long, even for a join, for tables of that size, unless your join was joining on non-unique keys so was taking time generating the cross-products of matching keys. For example:

```
SELECT t1.foo 
FROM (SELECT 1 as one, foo FROM table1) t1 
JOIN (SELECT 1 as one, bar FROM table2) t2
ON t1.one = t2.one
```

Would generate n x m rows where n is thenumber of rows in table1 and m is the number of rows in table2. Is there any chance your query is doing something similar? If not, can you send the query? (maybe in another SO question, related to slow join performance).

Comment: hi jordan. thank you for your asnwer, it was helpful. meanwhile over night my windoz installed updates and restarted himself to lost all my desktop work, so i can't even see whether it did finish the query or not. anyway, this was the query: `SELECT aa.e1, c.n_id_customer, count(*) from
(select a.i_euvn as e1, b.i_euvn as e2
FROM [ovca.ovca100k] a join [ovca.ovca100k] b 
on a.n_id_customer=b.n_id_customer) as aa
join [ovca.ovca100k] c 
on aa.e2=c.i_euvn
group each by 1,2 order by 1,3 desc;`

Comment: i was wrong, i can see the query result, generated 15 080 486 result rows.

Comment: and the weird thing is the resource usage didn't change at all. i still got only `Data Processed Per Day
14 MB` although i'm sure the query ate much more

Comment: The amount of data processed is reasonable, if your tables only have 10k-20k rows, since BigQuery only charges you for the amount of source data you processed.  But it does sound like the join is generating far more rows than you started out with.

Answer (score 1):

We didn't find a way to stop jobs while using the Java API, and as far as i know you can't stop a job at the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

if `bq cancel <job-id>` keeps failing with:

```
BigQuery error in cancel operation: Not found: Job <project-name>:<job-id>
```

then you will also have to provide the location.

```
bq --location <location> cancel <job-id>
```

For example,

```
bq --location europe-west2 cancel <job-id>
```